# Javascript for...in loop for objetcs not running on last property

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete, client-side-scripting

this is my first post in stackoverflow.. I am trying to iterate over an object(my implementation is an associative array) which in turn has some properties. Now I wish to construct another array out of it in order to use it as a localsource in jquery autocomplete widget for seach operations. Now the problem is that i am using for in loop to that according to the documenations available... However the output is always one less than the original object. The itearation involving the last element is not performed at all. Below is the sample object that I am using as input.

```
    SubTeachPair = object{"5CS1":{SubAbbrev:"CA-L",SubCode:"5CS1",SubName:"Computer Architecture",TeacherId:"1",TeacherName:"Ayush Pandey",label:"Computer Architecture",value:"5CS1"},"5CS2":{SubAbbrev:"CA-P",SubCode:"5CS2",SubName:"Computer Engg",TeacherId:"10",TeacherName:"MAyush Pandey",label:"Computer Engg",value:"5CS2"}}
```

It has this kind of elements and is dynamically generated so the property names are variable. The loop construct that I have written is

```
    var SubSource = [];
                console.log(SubTeachPair);
                var count = 0;


                for(sub in SubTeachPair){
                    console.log(count);
                    SubSource[count] = {};
                    SubSource[count]['label']=SubTeachPair[sub]['label'];
                    SubSource[count]['value']=SubTeachPair[sub]['value'];    
                    count++;    
                }
```

However, the result for the given input is only:

```
object{{ label: "Computer Architecture", value: "5CS1"}}
```

Am I missing something here?

edit-- The function that produces the input object is as follows(It is triggered onclick by the next button).

```
    $('#' + $(this).attr("id")).autocomplete({
                                           source : 'search',
                                           minLength : 1,
                                           change : function(event, ui) {
                                           if( typeof ui.item != 'undefined') {
                                           SubTeachPair[$(this).attr("id")] = {};
                                           //   console.log(ui.item);
                                           SubTeachPair[$(this).attr("id")]['value'] =  $(this).attr("id");
                                         SubTeachPair[$(this).attr("id")]['label'] = $('label[for="' + this.id + '"]').html();
                                           SubTeachPair[$(this).attr("id")]['SubCode'] = $(this).attr("id");
                                           SubTeachPair[$(this).attr("id")]['SubName'] =$('label[for="' + this.id + '"]').html();
                                           SubTeachPair[$(this).attr("id")]['SubAbbrev'] =$('label[for="' + this.id + '"]').attr('id');
                                           SubTeachPair[$(this).attr("id")]['TeacherId'] = ui.item.id;
                                            SubTeachPair[$(this).attr("id")]['TeacherName'] = ui.item.value;
                                        //  console.log(SubTeachPair);
                                            //window.SubTeachPair = SubTeachPair;

                                       }
                               }
                           });
```

I think I have found the cause of the error -- the object that is the input is actually the out put of another form that uses jquery autocomplete . Now when I enter something in the input and then click on the suggestion, the suggestion is filled in the text input, however if i do not click outside the input text and directly click the button which triggers my script, I get that error. Otherwise its fine. Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: Seems to work ok for me. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LzCRP/1/).

Comment: Can you include the declarations for the `count` and `SubSource` variables? The value of `count`, in particular, could be important.

Comment: your `sub` is an implicit global.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, the array `SubSource` and `count` are not defined, You have to declare:

```
var SubSource = [];
var count = 0`
```

before `for(sub in SubTeachPair) {...}`

See http://jsfiddle.net/abu5C/

Comment: I think, due to the fact he's getting **some** output rather than errors, that the variables are declared in his actual code and he simply didn't include that in the question.

Comment: mabe, but in the example (jsfiddle), when i added these 2 variables i got the good result.

Comment: The question states that he gets output which wouldn't happen if the problem was undeclared variables (he'd get JavaScript errors saying that the variables were undefined). This isn't the problem with his actual code, he just hasn't included everything that's relevant in the question.

Comment: your `sub` is an implicit global.

Comment: @jbabey Yes i know! This is the OP's code, i am not trying to optimize it, i am just looking to resolve his problem.

Comment: I have declared the variables count and SubSource , also I am not getting any error. Its just that the last property iteration does not happen. The loop terminates after (n-1) properties.

Comment: @user1606578 did you see this example http://jsfiddle.net/abu5C/? it is working good.

Comment: @m.abbas Yes it is working but I did the same thing now. I have the exact copy of the loop and its not working.

Comment: @m.abbas. infact the code IS working correctly in jsfiddle. thus that mean that there is some problem with the input object that I am creating dynamically(Using form inputs)? I will edit the question to include the function that generates the SubTeachPair object.

Comment: @m.abbas I think I have found the cause of the error -- the object that is the input is actually the out put of another form that uses jquery autocomplete . Now when I enter something in the input and then click on the suggestion, the suggestion is filled in the text input, however if i do not click outside the input text and directly click the button which triggers my script, I get that error. Otherwise its fine. Is there any way to avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SubSource[count] = {};

for(sub in SubTeachPair) {
    console.log(count);

    SubSource[count]['label']=SubTeachPair[sub]['label'];
    SubSource[count]['value']=SubTeachPair[sub]['value'];

    count++; 
}
```

Comment: your `sub` is an implicit global.

Comment: This will give an error once the count is incremented. The empty object initialisation needs to stay inside the loop.